# How do you find the angle needed to shoot a ball to a destination between two walls, for k bounces?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was working on one of my CS questions and came across a type of problem that I am unable to find resources for. The generalized form of the question is :

> What angle should a bowling ball be thrown in between two walls so that it bounces k times and hits a strike while bouncing at an angle of f(x), where x is the angle at which it hits the wall?

[It can be visualized like this, assuming that k (the number of bounces) is 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SXfv.png)

Comment: A common way to attack such problems is to “unfold” the path, reflecting the walls and target as necessary. The problem then reduces to finding a reflected target such that the line to it crosses the requisite number of walls.

Comment: @amd: that only works if $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve
$$\frac{\tan a}2 + \tan f(a)+\tan f(f(a))+\cdots +\tan f^{\circ(k-1)}(a)+\frac{\tan f^{\circ k}(a)}2 = \frac lw $$
for $a\in(0,\frac\pi2)$.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work! Is there a single formula way to do this? I'm asking because in the question I was reading $f(x) = arctan(2tan(a))$, which somehow simplifies the above to $a = arctan(L / (2k - 1) / 3 / (w / 2))$

Comment: Never mind found out how to simplify it. Thank you for helping me find out the answer with the formula above